# How to get information from broken key arguments - BS4 and Requests(Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I'm trying to get some information from an HTML page like this one using python, Requests and BeautifulSoup.

My issue is that I cant get the key arguments (like "Beginning Stocks" and "Domestic Crush") with the BeautifulSoup because they have a wrong "enter" broking the name.

It's weird because at the website they are not "broke".
I've never seen this before.

```
    <m1_region_group2 region4="World  2/">
        <m1_attribute_group2_collection>
            <m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Beginning
    Stocks">
                <cell cell_value4="77.73"></cell>
            </m1_attribute_group2>
            <m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Production">
                <cell cell_value4="313.77"></cell>
            </m1_attribute_group2>
            <m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Imports">
                <cell cell_value4="133.33"></cell>
            </m1_attribute_group2>
            <m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Domestic
    Crush">
                <cell cell_value4="275.36"></cell>
            </m1_attribute_group2>
            <m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Domestic
    Total">
                <cell cell_value4="314.35"></cell>
            </m1_attribute_group2>
            <m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Exports">
                <cell cell_value4="132.55"></cell>
            </m1_attribute_group2>
            <m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Ending
    Stocks">
                <cell cell_value4="77.92"></cell>
            </m1_attribute_group2>
        </m1_attribute_group2_collection>
    </m1_region_group2>
```

The 'Imports" and "production" arguments works well. For exemple:

```
    x.find("m1_attribute_group2", {"attribute4":"Imports"}).find("cell")["cell_value4"]
```

It returns '133.33'.

But when I try to get Domestic Total the result is "None", like BS couldn't find the argument.

```
   z = x.find("m1_attribute_group2", {"attribute4":"Domestic Total"})
```

Does anyone know what is going on? 
How can I fix it?

Mac OS Hight Sierra / Python3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more conservative approach would be to not even try to workaround the problem but **pre-process the HTML to get rid of the newlines in the element attributes**. Coincidentally, this is exactly [the problem we've recently solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47879227/771848):

```
In [25]: for tag in soup():
    ...:     tag.attrs = {
    ...:         attr: [" ".join(attr_value.replace("\n", " ").split()) for attr_value in value] 
    ...:               if isinstance(value, list)
    ...:               else " ".join(value.replace("\n", " ").split())
    ...:         for attr, value in tag.attrs.items()
    ...:     }
    ...:     

In [26]: soup.find("m1_attribute_group2", {"attribute4":"Domestic Total"})
Out[26]: 
<m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Domestic Total">
<cell cell_value4="314.35"></cell>
</m1_attribute_group2>
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I'm trying both right now. I'll keep you posted. But I think this second approach it better. I think is a good way to do with every html before work with it, isn`t it?

Comment: @CristianFavaroCarriço in my experience, this particular case (with newlines in the attribute values) is quite rare. I would only apply if needed. Thanks.

Comment: This worked pretty well! Thank you very much! But I have to confess that I couldn't understand the code. Got to study more. Is this regex?

Comment: @CristianFavaroCarriço nope, this is just basic string replacement. Going over all the tags and replacing the newlines in attribute values. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is just a non-well-formed HTML which `BeautifulSoup` is still capable of parsing. It's just that `attribute4="Domestic Total"` is never true since it's not the space that is between `Domestic` and `Total` but rather a newline character.

**One way** is to workaround with the `find()` method, using [a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) for the `attribute4` attribute value, split and re-join which would effectively remove all newlines and replace them with spaces:

```
In [19]: soup.find("m1_attribute_group2", attribute4=lambda x: x and " ".join(x.split()) == "Domestic Total")
Out[19]: 
<m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Domestic
    Total">
<cell cell_value4="314.35"></cell>
</m1_attribute_group2>
```

You can then generalize it as:

```
def filter_attribute(attr_value):
   def f(attr):
      return attr and " ".join(attr.split()) == attr_value
   return f
```

And use:

```
In [23]: soup.find("m1_attribute_group2", attribute4=filter_attribute("Domestic Total"))
Out[23]: 
<m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Domestic
    Total">
<cell cell_value4="314.35"></cell>
</m1_attribute_group2>
```

---

**Another approach** would be to use [a regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) and `\s+` as a delimiter between the words, where `\s+` means "one or more space characters including newline":

```
In [24]: soup.find("m1_attribute_group2", attribute4=re.compile(r"Domestic\s+Total"))
Out[24]: 
<m1_attribute_group2 attribute4="Domestic
    Total">
<cell cell_value4="314.35"></cell>
</m1_attribute_group2>
```

Comment: Both were great! Thank you!
But I think the second answer is a more safety way... With that, I can correct the entire html, right? I think i can use it as a function to correct futures problems.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what sir alecxe has already shown, you can do something like below as well if your requirement is to find any attribute correlated to it's earlier pair:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("m1_region_group2 m1_attribute_group2"):
    post = ' '.join(item['attribute4'].split())
    if "Beginning Stocks" in post:  #try to see if it misses any attribute
        val = item.find_next("cell")['cell_value4']
        print(val)
```

Result:

```
77.73
```

Comment: Try this as well if I didn't misunderstand your requirement.